# Resistor network in between SAW Filter and Power Amplifier

Tags: rf, filter, signal, impedance-matching, power-amplifier

I am going through user guide of `Microchip's` LoRaWan Gateway. The manual is over [here](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/40001827A.pdf). At page 48, I am struck at one resistor network and unable to understand it's use. I can make a guess and I think it is for reducing signal strength to a level acceptable by `power amplifier` at it's input. Below is the screenshot of the schematics page on page 48 of the manual:

[image]

According to current knowledge I have for RF designing, I have listed the blocks in above picture (encircled by different colors) with their functions:

1. Green: Resistor Network to attenuate signal so that Power amplifier can accept the signal power
2. Red: Impedance Matching Network
3. Blue: DC Blocking Caps.

Am I correct?

Comment: This particular power amplifier (the RFPA0133, datasheet [here](https://www.qorvo.com/products/d/da000936)) is rated for a maximum input power of 10dBm, but so is the [SAW filter](https://www.taisaw.com/upload/product/TA0547A%20_Rev.1.0_.pdf) that precedes it, so you would think any attenuation of the signal would come before the filter...

Comment: Then why they have that resistor network? I missed the specs of filter. I read it greater than 10 dbm accidentally.

Comment: I have no idea. It could still be an attenuator for some arcane RF magic.

Comment: If you compute the Impedance of each reactive part for the two different frequencies it will make more sense. Note that the pie filters to ground have the DNP for do not populate,So they do not provide much filtering per se, but may influence the phase shift, gain, Return loss around the band edges. If anything the R pad gives slightly more signal than a 50 Ohm R load so it terminates the SAW filter better with lower loss.

Comment: @TonyStewartolderthandirt Thanks for your comment. I would appreciate if you could explain a bit more so that person like me (RF beginner ) can understand in a better way?

Comment: Can you tell me the impedance of L5 and C37 for example at 867.5 and 917MHz for your understanding. There are the two optional SAW filters using the same reactive parts. This should answer your own question.

Comment: L5 => 44.69j (868) and 47.11j (915)
C37 => -3.275j (868) and -3.107j (915)

Comment: Am I correct for DC blocking caps and impedance matching network?

Comment: @TonyStewartolderthandirt I am not expert or even near to intermediate RF engineer. Please help me if I am not able to grasp your clues.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Can you help me with resistor network? Is it for absorb reflected energy? Why they have used specific values for resistors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**True the 56pF blocks DC but in some case sizes and brands is optimal for lowest ESR at Series Resonant Frequency (SRF)** *((which is often referred to as Self Resonant Freq. however there is also a higher Parallel Resonant Frequency (PRF) which is less commonly known or relevant}}*

In SMD603 size certain low cost ceramics , this is the optimal value for low Z DC blocking, as higher values become more inductive and lower values rise above > 10% of 50 Ohms so  this value has the lowest impedance at Self Resonance Frequency (SRF) for some types of ceramics.

Smaller RF physical capacitor SMD sizes can have higher SRF and different ceramic construction or cost or brands may have different SRF values, so it is wise to compare datasheets before selection and **have a second source.**

Then L5 value (8.2nH) is used for impedance matching just under 50 Ohms in combination with RF band filtering.  Caps with DNP are *Do Not Populate* are optional depending on board ground plane capacitance and L5 self capacitance.

The R Pi network appears to be a 2dB pad.

*(speculation) Depending on Rx input Resistance, there can also be a higher f notch filter with L5 and SRF in case of upper mobile band interference.

Answer (score 1):

Resistor network is there to absorb energy reflected by the down-stream lossless
filter.

Comment: Can you explain how values were calculated?

Comment: This is a PI-pad attenuator, just a few dB attenuation.

Comment: I am asking about values of resistors. Why these values?

Comment: @abhiarora: you need a Network of at least 3 elements because there are 3 degrees of freedom to be satisfied: (1) Input impedance (2) Output impedance (3) amount of attenuation. An alternative would be a T-network (also consisting of three resistors).

Comment: @Curd Can you help me with a formula to calculate Resistor values if Input impedance, Output impedance and amount of attenuation are known. Because If i design my own PCB, then impedance of PCB traces will vary according to it's environment.

Also, I think resistors can't alone help us with impedance matching (i know brief about smith chart). We will be needing L and C as well. Am I right?

Comment: @abhiarora: there are online calculators for this purpose, e.g. (the first I found googling) http://www.leleivre.com/rf_pipad.html